# How to enable Lollipop features(TranslucentStatus, colorButtonNormal, etc) in Kitkat

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-4.4-kitkat

i've developed an app which is currently working fine on `Lollipop` devices without any problem.but, there is a problem in `kitkat` and i can't find anything in manuals or ducumentation in **Android developers**.

for example, i have this theme in styles for everyscreens or android versions:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#43A047</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

and i had to use `tools:targetApi` for disabling the suggest or error.But, i need to use another features like **colorPrimaryDark**, **windowTranslucentStatusbar** and of course, `colorButtonNormal` In kitkat devices.and i had to delete this `windowTranslucentStatus` in V19 Style for showing them correctly in `kitkat`.

How we can do that or use these features in `Kitkat` like `lollipop`, i there any duc about this?

Thanks in advanced.!

Comment: Check out the support library - http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: i'm currently using this, but, what about the `colorPrimaryDark` in status bar or others? i'm using: https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView

Comment: as you can see, colorPrimaryDark in kitkat doesnt work!